# SQL to populate data for missing weeks

Tags: sql, database

I would like to build a sql to fill the missing weeks of data. Could you please help.

Example:

```
Year - Week    order
2018 W45        250
2018 W51        300
```

I would like the display to be as below:

```
Year - Week    order
2018 W45        250
2018 W46        250
2018 W47        250
2018 W48        250
2018 W49        250
2018 W50        250
2018 W51        300
...
2019 W52        300
```

Assuming the date end limit is 2019 December.

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What actually are you trying to do?.... could you be more specific?

Comment: In order to save space in the db - we are storing data only on weeks of change. I was wondering if I can use a sql to replicate the data in between the weeks so that I can display the data by weeks.

Comment: What database server are you using?  which version?

Answer (score 0):

On PostgreSQL you can try something like the following.

```
SELECT sq."year-week"
, sq.orders
FROM
(
SELECT LEFT(a.rstrt, 6) || W "year-week"
, a.orders
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(a.rstrt, 6) || W ORDER BY a.rend DESC) RN 
FROM(SELECT "year-week" rstrt
, COALESCE(LEAD ("year-week", 1) OVER(), 2018 || ' W' || 52) rend
, orders
FROM orders
UNION 
SELECT '2019 W01', '2019 W52', 300) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT generate_series(1, 52, 1) w) b ON b.w BETWEEN RIGHT(a.rstrt, 2)::INT AND RIGHT(a.rend, 2)::INT
ORDER BY LEFT(a.rstrt, 4)::INT, w
) sq
WHERE RN = 1;
```